# Variable reuse - which is better practice?

Tags: variables, reusability

Is reusing variables a good or bad thing or does it not make a difference?

Should I be doing this:

```
void someMethod (byte[] arrayOfBytes)
{
   byte[] newArrayOfBytes = someOtherMethod(arrayOfBytes);

   // ...
}
```

or this:

```
void someMethod (byte[] arrayOfBytes)
{
   arrayOfBytes = someOtherMethod(arrayOfBytes);

   // ...
}
```

or does it make no difference at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not lose any sleep on this.  The memory cost of the extra reference variable(s) is negligible.  I'd prefer the newArrayOfBytes method just for safety - it's not considered great practice to reassign a parameter coming into a method and it may lead to bugs later on, when a developer does not realise the parameter has changed to refer to another Object (you'll see some developers mark the method params as final, to prevent this)

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it without getting confused or confusing others then it is a good thing, because your code will require less memory.

Comment: ...at the expense of more CPU usage? or not?

Comment: Probably the language / compiler / runtime is a factor.  I don't see how it would work the CPU any harder though.